# Discord.py kick slash command not working

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@slash.slash(
    name="kick",
    description="Kick a member",
    guild_ids=[guildids],
    options=[
        create_option(
            name="user",
            description="The user I should kick",
            required=True,
            option_type=6
            ),
        create_option(
            name="reason",
            description="Why should I kick them?",
            required=False,
            option_type=3
            )
        ]
)
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def _kick(ctx:SlashContext, user:str, reason:str="None Given"):
    reason = str(reason)
    usr = "<@"+str(user.id)+">"
    await user.kick(reason)
    await user.send("Kicked from "+ctx.guild.name+" for "+reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Kicked a user", description="Kicked "+usr+" for reason: "+reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    print(ctx.author.name+" used: kick")


# ERRORS
@_kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx:SlashContext, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Permission Error")
        embed.add_field(name="Missing:", value="Kick Members")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When I do /kick user reason nothing happend, it just gives the interaction failed. It doesnt even kick the user or send a message to them saying they where kicked. I have no idea what is going on because of my little experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use `user:str`. It converts `user` to string but you can not kick `str` object. Just write `user` instead of `user:str`.

Also note that it is better to use `user.mention` instead of `"<@"+str(user.id)+">"` and read about [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) in python.

Comment: user:str does not convert it to a string. It is an annotation used in Python to tell the user what type of data this variable accepts/want.

Answer (score -3):

Discord.py is now deprecated and there is no guarantee it will work or not in 2022. I could suggest you to shift to some other discord library or move to Javascript as it support / commands.

Here is the original post of discord.py discontinued: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1/

Comment: The author of the question uses discord-interactions library with d.py to create slash commands. I think that your response doesn’t answer the question.